# C programming: Generating a random number (x) that is between -2,2 and then updating x

Tags: c, while-loop, srand

Im trying to write a program to randomly generate a number (term x) between [-2,2]. I then want to update the term using a while loop.

I know how to use drand48() and srand() but I know I cant use drand48() for this since it only computes numbers between 0 and 1.

Im only about a month in to using C so im still pretty confused about it all.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [so] ... Have you tried something? HINT: if you have a randomly generated real number between [0, 1] you can expand it to a number between [0, 4] by multiplying the originally generated random number by 4.

Comment: `x = rand() % 5 - 2;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `drand48()`, you get the range [0.0, 1.0).

(This is a half-open interval, because drand won't return 1.0, only things very close to 1.)

If you multiply the return value `drand48()` by 4, you get the range [0.0, 4.0).

If you subtract 2 from `4*drand48()`, you get the range [-2.0, 2.0).

So, therefore:

```
4*drand48() - 2
```

PS: I assume you're trying to generate a real number, not an integer. If you're trying to get an integer, use the `rand()` solution that @WeatherVane posted.

Comment: Okay that makes a lot of sense! So would I use the same approach if I wanted to shorten the range from -1,1? Sorry if thats an obvious question I just know that C tends to be picky

Comment: Yeah, pretty much.